# Cannot retrieve cell data in Openpyxl using variable as location

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to be able to get the value of a cell via openpyxl using a for loop  and using a string and the string of an integer counter as a location.

eg. "A" + str(Counter) = A1
    get the value from cell A1

then so on and so on A2, A3...

but i receive

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'

I've already tried combining a variable containing string A and the string of an integer outside of the for loop and it returns the value of the cell.

```
import openpyxl

COUNTER_RESET = -1

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(FILE_AND_PATH)
ws = wb.active


for row in ws:
    COUNTER_RESET = COUNTER_RESET + 1 #----counter goes from 0 til end
    COUNTER_STRING = str(COUNTER_RESET)
    location_temp_A = "A" + COUNTER_STRING
    row_parts1 = ws [location_temp_A].value
    print(row_parts1)
```

I want it to print the value of the cell each time. When i know it gets the value i can then get it to add to a list. Instead I get:

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: You should always use `ws.cell(row=x, column=y)` or `ws.iter_rows()` for this kind of task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was starting at -1, as there is no A0 cell.

Comment: Just a note - the whole `COUNTER_RESET = -1`, `COUNTER_RESET = COUNTER_RESET + 1` is a *horrible* kludge. I suggest looking at [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), adjusting the start-index as necessary.

Comment: `ws.iter_rows()` does all the counting for you anyway, used also by the row iterator. That's not actually the source of the error here. There is presumably some code involving `row` that is missing.